# Does JCR (java content repository) store videos?

Tags: video, content-management-system, jcr

Does JCR (java content repository) store videos ?
The reason I am asking, I saw one of the open source cms called Hippo and they embed videos from vimeo in their website rather than having stored it on content repository.

I appreciate any input.

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible to do. In fact JCR can store binary data including videos,images, documents etc...Then,you will need just to read the content of the binary and stream it in a video reader.
You can watch a simple usage on [eXo Platform](http://www.exoplatform.com) they are using JCR as their storage and they are providing a video player on their Social streams and their JCR browser (Content Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Embedding videos from online services can be useful to avoid the bandwidth and infrastructure costs of streaming videos yourself. That being said, as Ali says JCR can store any binary, but you'll need to check the performance of a given JCR implementation against your use cases to make an informed decision.